# R shiny app doesn't print to console

Tags: r, console, shiny

I am implementing an R shiny application. I am using cat and print to write to the console and be able to see what is going on.

In the server.R I have some calls to cat before the shinyServer function and they work well.
I have though other calls to cat inside shinyServer and their content is not printed although the code is executed, I see the output in the web UI, they are in a reactive block. 
The UI.R uses a submitButton in case this makes a difference.

As far as I have read, cat should send to console unless redirected, what I am not doing.
I am also using cat with file="" and file=stdout() to try avoid any redirection.

If I run the app from a shortcut on the console that gets open the situation is the same.
Any ideas on what can be happening?

I use R 3.1.1 and R studio 0.98 in Windows 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shiny: What is the option setting to display in the console the messages between server and ui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002712/shiny-what-is-the-option-setting-to-display-in-the-console-the-messages-between)

Comment: @topchef no, I don't refer to this setting that shows the communication between client and server. I refer to include my own messages on the console

Comment: since I made the question I have found that I can see the messages if I use file=stderr() but I still don't understand why there is a default redirection and how to revert it

Comment: Its very difficult to speculate on the answer without an example. I can suggest you check that the 'print' isnt at the end of any reactive expression. You can further look here where you can maybe use message("my personal msg") http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533284/difference-between-paste-and-print-effecting-result-of-function or there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775085/the-difference-between-concatenating-character-strings-with-paste-vs-cat

Comment: @pops, message gets the job done but I would like to know while cat doesn't work even when I set file=stdout() and when it works for stderr(). I give you +1

Comment: I had similar problem: it disappeared after upgrading shiny package (I saw discussion thread about it but can't locate it anymore).

Comment: found it: http://goo.gl/iYFGQ7

Comment: @topchef, thanks I will update my shiny version after I finish this project... I already upgraded in a new machine I had to setup and found bugs on other parts so I had to revert to the versions on my dev machine... with the message and cat stderr thing I will survive so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading shiny (currently 0.10.2.1) resolved this problem for me. Also, see related discussion [here](http://goo.gl/iYFGQ7).