# Use of paste with print

Tags: r

Why print is used with paste in R?

```
speed <- 31

print(paste("Your speed is", speed))
# [1] "Your speed is 31"

paste("Your speed is", speed))
# [1] "Your speed is 31"
```

Comment: Because `paste()` makes a character vector and `print()` prints. Just because you see output interactively when you invoke `paste()` doesn't mean that you're going to see it that way in a non-interactive script or function call.  Also, thx @JJJ for muting the shouting.

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/11533369/382936

Comment: @SethDifley:  I don't understand the downvotes since I thought the question was about the basic behavior of the R console and failing to understand the implicit `print` call for every completed expression. I did do a search for a duplicate but didn't find one, but willing to offer a close hammer vote.

Comment: I am not sure if it is a duplicate. If it's not a duplicate, it should not be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You have to include print() when you want to produce output from within a function. For example:

```
x <- function(){
       speed <- 31
       paste("Your speed is", speed)
       y = 3
  }
```

won't print anything but this will:

```
x <- function(){
 speed <- 31
  print(paste("Your speed is", speed))
  y = 3
}
```

Comment: That's a fairly incomplete answer and I'm not sure it address the question. (There was no `function(.){.}` code in the question. It fails to mention `cat` and because it doesn't discuss environments. A reader would have little added understanding of the underlying programming models and therefore it fails to mention the "super-assign" option.

Answer (score 1):

R is an interpreted language and the console has a user-interface that is a "REPL", a read-evaluate-print-loop. User input is first evaluated and then the interpreter looks for a `print`-function that is specific for the class of the item being returned. You can see the list (although it's not an R-"list") by typing this at the console:

```
 methods(print)   # it's a fairly long listing.
```

So using print() around an expression at the console level is not doing anything different than the usual R interpreter does. The other function to get familiar with is `cat` which has the sometimes useful feature of not putting quotes around "printed" values and not have an implicit carriage-return at the end. Many print-methods will give an abbreviated output that uses `cat` to construct summarized results. If you really wnat to see what is in an object you then need to use `str` or `dput`.